# Como compilar um arquivo .java usando o terminal do ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Sou um usuário iniciante e preciso compilar um arquivo .java usando o terminal do ubuntu, como proceder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Com o JDK (Java SE Development Kit) instalado, pode ser usado o javac, que é um compilador para a linguagem Java.

Para compilar o código java, o comando é o seguinte:

```
$ javac SeuCodigo.java
```

Após executado o comando acima, se não for informado NADA no seu terminal é porque a compilação foi executada com sucesso. Posteriormente, pode-se notar que foi gerado um arquivo no diretório em que seu código foi compilado.

Para executá-lo, execute o comando abaixo:

```
$ java SeuCodigo
```

Esse arquivo gerado nada mais é que seu programa java compilado.

Comment: Precisa estar no mesmo diretório ou pelomenos indicar o path do file.

Answer (score 5):

para compilar um arquivo .java, abra o termia e execute o seguinte comando

```
javac arquivo.java
```

E  para executar o arquivo de classe gerado, use

```
java arquivo
```

Answer (score 2):

Em que momento você está ? Já instalou a JDK(Java Development Kit) ? Este kit possui o javaC que é o javaCompiler (programa que irá compilar seus arquivos .java). Se possitivo, vamos em frente, caso contrário baixe e instale a JDK.

Em frente:
Já criou o arquivo com a extensão .java ? Você pode cria-lo com um editor de texto simples salvando-o como NomeDaClasse.java (espero que neste momento, você saiba a estrutura básica de uma classe, caso contrário o problema está antes da compilação em sí).

Com o arquivo NomeDaClasse.java criado, abra seu terminal e vá caminhando pelas pastas até chegar ao local deste arquivo (acho que no Ubunto você pode clicar com botão direito em qualquer local da pasta em aberto e colocar abrir no terminal). Então você executa o comando javac NomeDaClasse.java se não houver nenhum erro encontrado pelo compilador, o terminal pulará para uma nova linha aguardando a execução de um novo comando qualquer. Neste momento se tudo ocorreu com sucesso, foi criado o arquivo NomeDaClasse.class para rodar seu programa agora você deve usar o comando java NomeDaClasse (somente sem extensão nenhuma).

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá, no caso as maquinas da faculdade já possuem o JDK, mas se você puder explicar como instalar o JDK através de linha de comando seria ótimo.

Comment: Você pode obter as informações detalhadas sobre a instalação do JDK neste link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-o-java-no-ubuntu-com-apt-get-pt